# Magento 2 call APIexternal

Tags: magento2, api

I am new to Magento 2, I am trying to make a **web service**, for the communication of an *e-commerce* in an ERP system, I already have the ERP communication in Magento (example: I insert a product from the ERP system, and it is also done in commerce ), with the help of its API Rest ([API rest](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/)), but now I require that if any change is made in *e-commerce* (for example an order) the change is also made in the *ERP system* thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will have to observe those particular events for e.g if an customer is created as soon
as it is created you can send those detail using API to the ERP. Check with the ERP if the customer is present by email if exist than no need to save if not you can save it.

Comment: yes i am sure you should use watchers and events, the problem is connecting to external API for magento, you should use cURL connection,